# How to show $x_{k}=\frac{(I-\alpha Q)^{k} x_{0}}{\left\|(I-\alpha Q)^{k} x_{0}\right\|}$ where Q is positive definite, converges to optimal solution

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to show $\overrightarrow x_{k}=\frac{(I-\alpha Q)^{k} \overrightarrow x_{0}}{\left\|(I-\alpha Q)^{k} \overrightarrow x_{0}\right\|}$ where $\overrightarrow x_{k}$ converges to an optimal solution as k tends to infinity. This is an update equation in Optimization.

Q is positive definite, real nxn, and the eigenvalues are distinct. $  x_{0}$ is also not orthogonal to the eigenvector of Q with smallest eigenvalue

I need to show for $0<\alpha<1 / \lambda_{\max }$ , the fixed step size converges to an optimal solution. $\lambda_{\max }$ max eigenvalue of Q

*My attempt is to try and factorize. so $x_{k}=\frac{(I-\alpha V\Sigma V^{T})^{k} \sum ^{n}_{i=1}\mu _{i}\overrightarrow {v_{i}}}{\left\|I-\alpha V\Sigma V^{T})^{k} \sum ^{n}_{i=1}\mu _{i}\overrightarrow {v_{i}}\right\|}$ and take $\lim _{k\rightarrow \infty }$
Where $v_{i}$ is eigenbasis of Q*

*And then something with the terms to the power of k tending to 0.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:
$(I-\alpha Q)=V(I- \alpha D)V^T$

where $V$ is orthogonal and $D$ diagonal and $VDV^T=Q$.

$(I-\alpha Q)^k=V(I- \alpha D)^k V^T$

note that $(I- \alpha D)$ is diagonal, so $(I- \alpha D)^k$ are just the diagonal entries to the power of $k$. Denote $\lambda_i=D_{ii}$ the $i$-th eigenvalue.

For the $i$-th diagonal entry it holds:

$(I- \alpha D)^k_{ii}=(1-\lambda_{min}\alpha)^k \frac{(1-\alpha \lambda_i)^k}{(1-\lambda_{min}\alpha)^k}$

$\frac{(I- \alpha D)^k_{ii}}{(1-\lambda_{min}\alpha)^k}= \frac{(1-\alpha \lambda_i)^k}{(1-\lambda_{min}\alpha)^k}$

In the limit, the right hand side is equal $1$ if $\lambda_i=\lambda_{min}$ and $0$ else.

This implies $\frac{V(I- \alpha D)^kV^T}{(1-\lambda_{min}\alpha)^k}\to v_{min}v_{min}^T$

Now, it is easy to show, that $x_k \to v_{min}$ (the eigenvector to the smalest eigenvalue)

Edit:
For the formal proof, use $ x_{k}=\frac{\frac{(I-\alpha Q)^{k} }{(1-\lambda_{min}\alpha)^k} x_{0}}{\left\|\frac{(I-\alpha Q)^{k}}{(1-\lambda_{min}\alpha)^k}  x_{0}\right\|}\to \frac{v_{\min}v_{\min}^T x_0}{\left\|v_{\min}v_{\min}^T x_0\right\|}=v_{\min}$

We can take these limits because everything is finite.

Comment: Thanks, this looks right. I'm not getting it completely. I get that $(I-\alpha D)^{k} $ is diagonal and each entry is $(I-\alpha D)_{i i}^{k}$ I get that $\frac{\left(1-\alpha \lambda_{i}\right)^{k}}{\left(1-\lambda_{\min } \alpha\right)^{k}}$ is 1 at the limit if lambda min. because you are dividing by something bigger for the others.

Comment: I don't think I get it. Seems magical to pull out minimum eigen value. Is it that limit of  $\left(1-\lambda_{\min } \alpha\right)^{k} \frac{V\left(1-\alpha \lambda_{i}\right)^{k}V^{T}}{\left(1-\lambda_{\min } \alpha\right)^{k}} =1 . \boldsymbol{v}_{\min } \boldsymbol{v}_{\min }^{\boldsymbol{T}}$?

Comment: So currently this is what I think you are doing $\lim _{k\rightarrow \infty }V\left(1-\alpha D\right)^{k}V^{T}$ = $\lim _{k\rightarrow \infty }$$\left(1-\lambda_{\min } \alpha\right)^{k} \frac{v_{i}\left(1-\alpha \lambda_{i}\right)^{k}v_{i}}{\left(1-\lambda_{\min } \alpha\right)^{k}}= 1.v_{i}\delta _{i\min }v_{i} =1 . \boldsymbol{v}_{\min } \boldsymbol{v}_{\min }^{\boldsymbol{T}}$? using a bit of index notation. I'm not sure if you can take limits like that, the limits of the products seperately. Is this right?

Comment: Also do you think there is a mistake in the question with $0<\alpha<1 / \lambda_{\max },$ should it be $0<\alpha<1 / \lambda_{\min }$ so the limit of $\left(1-\lambda_{\min } \alpha\right)^{k}=1 ?-$ Or is it actually correct, and something to do with the condition number?

Comment: Sorry if my thoughts were unclear, i've edited my solution. And $0<\alpha<1 / \lambda_{\max }$ is right, it is necessary, to keep the diagonal elemets larger than zero, i.e. $0<(I-\alpha D)_{ii}<1$ for every $i$

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, this is so helpful. ah ok. No it's not you being unclear, just my lack of ability. Yes its a stronger condition on $\alpha$, so they are all less than 1 so converge at the limit. That makes sense to me

Comment: Just to make sure I understand did I get the right idea with this step $$\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} \left(1-\lambda_{\min } \alpha\right)^{k} \frac{V\left(1-\alpha \lambda_{i}\right)^{k} V^{T}}{(1-\lambda \min \alpha)^{k}}= \lim _{k \rightarrow \infty}(\left(1-\lambda_{\min } \alpha\right)^{k}). $$ $$\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty}( \frac{V\left(1-\alpha \lambda_{i}\right)^{k} V^{T}}{(1-\lambda \min \alpha)^{k}})$$ =$ 1 . v_{\min } v_{\min }^{T}$ ? right . So you take the limits of each. This is basic analysis that is ok to do

Comment: $\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty}\left(1-\lambda_{\min } \alpha\right)^{k} =0$ since $\left |1-\lambda_{\min } \alpha \right |<1$. So, note that it is important to cancle this term out with the denominator.

Comment: Ok thanks so much for your help, I get it now :). I guess I was stuck with basic Analysis. Cheers, it seems a trick to me that you might have had to have seen before hand unless you are really smart to know to factor out smallest eigenvalue term.